Python Pandas reads inconsistent date formats from Excel files generated automatically with a 3rd part API
I'm using the PDF4me API to convert PDF invoices into Excel files. The dates are read correctly by the API. However, when I open the Excel files, the dates are displayed inconsistently:

Some dates appear in the correct format (dd/mm/yyyy), while others are displayed in the incorrect mm/dd/yyyy format. This inconsistency seems to occur when the day of the month is less than or equal to 12.

Although the incorrectly formatted dates initially appear as dd/mm/yyyy, they revert to mm/dd/yyyy when I click on the cell.

If I convert the Excel file to CSV, all dates appear in the correct dd/mm/yyyy format.
Desired Behavior:

I want all dates in the Excel files to be consistently formatted as dd/mm/yyyy, regardless of whether the day of the month is less than or equal to 12. This should also be consistent with how Pandas reads the dates.


Current Behavior:
When I read the Excel files into a Pandas DataFrame, the date format inconsistencies cause problems in my analysis. I cannot manually correct these issues because the Excel files are generated automatically.
Additional Notes:

The PDF invoices themselves have dates in the correct dd/mm/yyyy format.
I suspect this is due to Excel's automatic date formatting based on regional settings.
I cannot directly control the PDF4me API's Excel generation process.

Question:
How can I ensure that the dates in the Excel files are consistently formatted as dd/mm/yyyy when read into Pandas, or how can I make Pandas read the dates correctly despite the inconsistencies?
Example Data:



Invoice Date (Excel Display)
Invoice Date (Actual Value when Clicked)




20/07/2024
20/07/2024


04/06/2024
06/04/2024



Code Blcok: (Already Tried following options)
# Read the Excel file into a DataFrame
xls = pd.ExcelFile(excel_path)

for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names[:-1]:
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=sheet_name,
         date_format="%d.%m.%Y")


# Tried this in old versions
df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=sheet_name,
         date_format="%d.%m.%Y", dayfirst=True)

Screenshots form Excel
[![In this case, the visible date is the same as the actual value][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Zfa2HdmS.png
[![In this case, the visible date is in a different format][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/JfGA8Ya2.png

Smells like Excel trying to be clever and ruining your day by shooting you in the foot. Maybe this helps: try to read the dates as strings, then convert to datetime once you have a pd.Dataframe. pd.to_datetime takes a keyword dayfirst=True if you have dd/mm/yyyy format in the input string.

@FObersteiner I tried to read it as text, but it still reads the underlying date (in the wrong format) and not the one visible in Excel. I tried to use dayfirst=True in the previous version of pandas but then I updated the pandas version to try a new parameter in pandas which is "date_format". Didn't work. I'll try again.

Be assured that this is an Excel issue and not a pandas issue, I've stumbled across this in the past as well. What you can do to get a better understanding of what works and what doesn't, you can change the column format in Excel to "text" or "number", then see how that affects what you get on the Python side.

@FObersteiner I'll do that. Thanks

in my case, I ended up using the excel loader engine directly in Python, to get more control over datetime conversion: just found my post from back then. Not sure though if that works in your case.
